# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION for empty project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How do I solve this?
I installed Android Studio on a new computer, I opted for a new Project, I followed the wizard and then without adding any code and without changing anything in the generated files I tried to run the new app. 
This is what I get :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output F:\==Android\TestingGradle2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-e311e493b238b75da4095bd5ee7b69d76d73dc42.jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Android\TestingGradle2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-e311e493b238b75da4095bd5ee7b69d76d73dc42.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    1 error; aborting
```

**UPDATE**
[image]

The build.gradle generated looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.mycomp.calinutz.testgradle4"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

The problem did not occur from the start... I managed to create a test app right after installing, but then I tried to import a project created on a different computer (the old one). I did not succeed, so I went on and recreated the project manually (copy paste of the relevant code).
At the end, when I wanted to run the recreated project , this error occured. And ever since then, any new empty project I start, the same error occurs.

**HOWEVER, I CAN STILL RUN MY FIRST TEST APP ?!?!?!?!** Why? Why does that one work, and no other project? I compared the 2 build.gradle files (original project and new empty project) and there is absolutely no difference. 
Does this have something to do with writing rights on this Windows 8.1 system? I start the Android Studio as Administrator, so it should not have any problems like that...? But what is it then?

**IMPORTANT**
I think I have narrowed down the problem:

**It seems that if I create the new project on partition F, instead of partition C, this error occurs.**

So if my new project is located on Local Disk C - it works fine 
If my new project  is located on Local Disk F - it throws the aforementioned error.

What can I do? I cannot put all my projects on C because it is a SSD drive and it's small.
I went to Properties->Sharing->Advanced Sharing->Permissions for the F drive and set them to Full Access.
Then I went to Properties-> Security and made sure all users listed there have Full Access to the drive.
Still - same problem.

Please help me
How can I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: do you have the android support library 7+ version 19.1.0 installed?

Comment: I dfo not think so, because in my SDK Manager I only see the above libraries (in the picture in the question). So I do not know if the support library is v7 because I can only see the revision and that is 20

Comment: This problem happened to me as well, without any apparent reason. The solution I found was to enable proguard to remove unused classes (in `build.gradle`).

Comment: I tryied something like that but didn't work. Can you elaborate please? Maybe I did it wrong. Do I make changes in the projects build.gradle or in the higher one? What exactly are the changes? Why can't it work "out of the box"?

Comment: Sorry, my error was not the same, and I could not manage to find any information about it. Maybe you can try to submit the error on the [Android project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: I just did that, but maybe I can find the solution here if others encountered too this problem... I have no idea on how fast the bugs are solved and I am on a schedule :(

Answer (score 0):

You have Support library version 20 installed, but are telling gradle to look for version 19.

change the dependency line to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

and it should work correctly

Comment: First, I do not have support v4 (apparently) and I use v7 instead. However I have the setting you suggest in my new project, but still the same error appears. I will add the gradle.build in the question body above to avoid confusions

Comment: Also I uninstalled the Android Studio, then re-downloaded it, then I reinstalled the SDKs, then again I started a new project. The error stays the same. HOWEVER, if I try to run an older project, that was done before reinstalling the first time... it works with no problem whatsoever... WTF?