# Android Studio and Windows 8

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 system with latest Android-Studio.
Now, when I create a new project, if I set it's path to be on partition Local Disk F, I will receive errors.
If I set the path of the project to be on Local Disk C, no errors appear.

What is the solution to this?
The errors that appear, are like:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output F:\==Android\TestingGradle2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-e311e493b238b75da4095bd5ee7b69d76d73dc42.jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
...
file not found...
```

So the real problem is with the **location of the Project**
What can I do to solve this?
I cannot have all my dummy projects in Local Disk C because it is a SSD drive and it is small.

I noticed that all my folders on my F drive are read only, and do not have writing access priviledges, so I did the following steps so far:

- I went to Properties->Sharing->Advanced Sharing->Permissions for the F drive and set them to Full Access.
- Then I went to Properties-> Security and made sure all users listed there have Full Access to the drive

After this, still no change. The error keeps appearing every time I try a new project or old one that is located on that F drive.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: did you try running Android Studio as admin?

Comment: Yes I did, no change

Comment: This is a rewording of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438919/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception-for-empty-project. Please ask the same question only once.

Comment: Yes, however, the initial question was considering a possible bug inside Android Studio, while this one presumes an incompatibility with Windows 8. Also whoever reads a question is 'scared' by too much text and tends to skip the question. That is why I rephrased the question in a new one, to point to the exact problem

Comment: Also, after my discovery of the Windows 8 problem... there are no more replies on the initial question, so I assume, nobody saw the update and still thinks of the initial problem... So that is why I decided to make a new one with only the actual problem